# Set default value for Radio Choice - Wicket

Tags: java, radio-button, wicket

I want to set my Radio Choice to "Sim" by default, how can I do that?

My custom Radio Choice class:

```
package com.sges.web.components;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.RadioChoice;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;

public class RadioSimNao extends RadioChoice<Boolean> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public RadioSimNao(String id, IModel<Boolean> model) {
        super(id, model, new ArrayList<Boolean>(Arrays.asList(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE)), new BooleanChoiceRenderer());
        add(AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior.onUpdateChoice(target -> target.add(getThis())));
    }

    private RadioSimNao getThis() {
        return this;
    }

}
```

Here's where I initialize it.

```
dispoeGeradoresEmergenciaChoice = new RadioSimNao("dispoeGeradoresEmergencia",null);
dispoeGeradoresEmergenciaChoice.setEnabled(false);
dimensao_enquadramento_container.add(dispoeGeradoresEmergenciaChoice);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 

```
super(id, model, new ArrayList<Boolean>(Arrays.asList(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE)), new BooleanChoiceRenderer());
```

Here you say that the RadioChoice may have two possible values: `TRUE` and `FALSE`

2.

```
dispoeGeradoresEmergenciaChoice = new RadioSimNao("dispoeGeradoresEmergencia",null);
```

Here you pass `null` as a model for the selected value. If you want to pre-select any of the possible values then you should pass `Model.of(true)` or `Model.of(false)`

It is not clear what do you mean with `Sim` in `I want to set my Radio Choice to "Sim" by default`. "Sim" is not in the possible value (TRUE | FALSE).

Comment: I was passing null because I didn't know what to put there to make a default selection. 
Putting Model.of(true) helped making it selected on "Sim" aka true. My RadioSimNao automatically changes the true to Sim and false to Nao.
Thanks a lot.